# Can SQL queries across namespaces be made?

Tags: sql, odbc, intersystems, intersystems-iris

Is it possible to make a query across tables in different namespaces?

Eg:

```
select A.TS as A_TS, B.TS as B_TS 
from ns1.schema.table as A left join ns2.schema.table as B on A.id = B.id
```

At least, is it possible to get tables `A` and `B` using the same ODBC connection? As far as I can see, the namespace is established when making the connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to do it is by using namespace as it is supposed to be, you can add package and global mapping, to new or existing namespace/s. So, desired tables will be available from one namespace together.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, that won't be enough in my setup. I want to access tables with same names and structure in many different namespaces.